# Fill an array of strings until a sentinel value is found

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, sentinel

I'm trying to read strings into an array until the user enters the sentinel string, which is "XXX".
 I don't want the sentinel value stored in the array. How do I avoid putting the sentinel value into the array?

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 15
typedef char string15[MAXCHAR+1];

void
getInputs(string15 word[], int *nElem)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<30 && strcmp(word[i-1], "XXX")!=0)
    {
        printf("Input word %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", word[i]);
        i++;

        if(i<=8 && strcmp(word[i-1], "XXX")==0)
        {
            printf("Below Minimum Count\n");
            printf("Input word %d: ", i);
            scanf("%s", word[i-1]);
        }
    }
    (*nElem)=i-1;
}

int main()
{
    int nElem;
    string15 word[30];
    getInputs(word, &nElem);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "ignore the sentintel"? You haven't told us what it is you want to do with the non-sentinel data. "My array takes in the inputted sentinel value to the array I created". Huh? What does it mean for an array to "take the inputted sentinel"? It might help if you give some solid examples of input and expected output or expected behaviour.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here. I also strongly discourage the typedef trick you're trying to play. C doesn't have strings, and you're only making your code harder to debug by trying to pretend that it does.

Comment: @ stevie I tried to guess your intent. Please feel free to rollback or revise if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to edit your code as little as possible while making it make sense...

```
void getInputs(string15 word[], int *nElem)
{
    int i = 0;
    char buffer[128];
    while(i<30)
    {
        printf("Input word %d: ", i+1);
        fgets(buffer, 128, stdin);

        if (strcmp(buffer, "XXX\n") != 0) {
          strncpy(word[i], buffer, 15);
          i++;
        } else {
          if (i<=8) {
            printf("Below Minimum Count\n");
            continue;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
    }
    (*nElem) = i;
}
```

To be honest, though, there are other design issues as well.  For example, why doesn't your function return the number of character strings added, rather than modifying an integer to which you're passed a pointer?